# Selenium-Chrome-Headless : Unable to receive message from renderer

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, jenkins, headless

I am using 
Chrome-latest stable version `61.0.3163.79`
Chomedriver 2.31
Selenium 3.4.0
Jenkins and docker

My first run over Jenkins getting error as below:

> 1.732][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer [1.732][DEBUG]:
>   DevTools request: http://localhost:12059/json [1.733][DEBUG]: DevTools
>   request failed

Can someone please assist me how can I solve this?

Comment: can you add the code you are using. it will give better understading to all of us to help you better

Comment: is your code working fine without headless?

Comment: Try [**`Mozilla Firefox in Headless Mode`**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPS89xCgNhk&t=528s)

Comment: This is first time we are trying on headless, earlier we are using phantomjs

Comment: ` chromeOptions.addArguments(dimension);
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "target/chromedriver.log");

        ChromeDriverService service =
                new ChromeDriverService.Builder().withWhitelistedIps("").withVerbose(true).build();

        driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
        driver.get(domain); `

Comment: we are running this from jenkins

Answer (score 0):

```
chromeOptions.addArguments(dimension);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
    Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium.remote").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "target/chromedriver.log");
    ChromeDriverService service =
            new ChromeDriverService.Builder().withWhitelistedIps("").withVerbose(true).build();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
    driver.get(domain);
```

---

also mount volumes on server:
/dev/shm:/dev/shm

This fixed my issue