# Chromedriver on linux : [SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, amazon-ami

Whatever I try, I always end up with the same message when trying to run Selenium Java with WebDriver

google-chrome-stable version:

> Google Chrome 73.0.3683.75

Chrome Driver Version:

> 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72)

Java library version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_201"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build> 1.8.0_201-b09)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

I used the following options :

```
    options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
    options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");
    options.addArguments("--headless", // Headless chrome
                    "window-size=1680,970", // window size
                    "--no-sandbox", // avoid bugs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d
                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage" // avoid bugs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d
                    );
```

`driver.get(someUrl);` works

Then, i call a simple WebDriverWait

```
element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout))
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
```

I always have the message :

> [SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer

Such code worked like a charm on a previous jenkins server ( hosted on EC2- Linux AMI), and we migrated to a new one, at the same time we upgraded chrome version.

Please help me i'm getting crazy :'(

Note: i already tried what is described on [Selenium-Chrome-Headless : Unable to receive message from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074384/selenium-chrome-headless-unable-to-receive-message-from-renderer) so this is not a duplicate, as the versions are not the same.

Comment: i already tried what is described on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051117/error-severe-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-20-000-while-executin so this is not a duplicate, as the versions are not the same, please can you unmark as duplicate ?